# How to make a json request on a graphql endpoint built with graphene and flask

Tags: python, flask, graphql, graphene-python, flask-graphql

I have a flask app and I am using graphene to build some graphql endpoints. The following snippet is to build the `metadata_by_config` query.

```
engine = create_engine('postgres_url', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class MetadataModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = "metadata"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    config = Column(String(255), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, config, description):
        self.created = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.config = config


class Metadata(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = MetadataModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


# Query
class QueryID(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()

    metadata_by_id = graphene.List(Metadata, id=graphene.String())

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_metadata_by_id(parent, info, **args):
        q = args.get('id')

        metadata_query = Metadata.get_query(info)
        return metadata_query.filter(MetadataModel.id == q).all()

# schema
schema_id = graphene.Schema(query=QueryID, types=[Metadata])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


app.add_url_rule(
    '/graphql-id',
    view_func=GraphQLView.as_view(
        'graphql-id',
        schema=schema_id,
        graphiql=True
    )
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This works fine when I do the request in the graph query language, following works:

```
q = """
{
  metadataById (id: 1){
  id
  created
  config
}
}
"""

resp = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/graphql-id", params={'query': q})
print(resp.text)
```

However, since it's graphene, there is no separate graphql server (code-first approach). Therefore I am trying to figure out if there is a way to abstract away the graph query language knowledge from the end-user where a user doesn't need to know gql or backend implementation details. The user should just be able to make JSON request like `requests.post("http://localhost:5000/graphql-id", json={'id': 1})` as if its a rest API and then the server parse the JSON and prepare the appropriate query probably inside resolver method.

I was thinking to handle this scenario using the redirects (expososing another endpoint that talk to graphql endpoint) and have `graphql-config` endpoint accessible only on localhost by adding a condition on `app.before_request` something like following:

```
@app.before_request
    def before_request():
        if request.remote_addr != "127.0.0.1" and request.path == "/v1/graphql-config":
            abort(403)
```

However, this seems a little hacky and vulnerable, is there any explicit or better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I didn't realize we can actually execute our schema and so we dont need to use `GraphQLView` of `flask-graphql` to create an endpoint. So I have implemented my endpoint as following:

```
@app.route('/getMetadata', methods=['GET'])
def getMetadata():
    data = request.get_json()
    MetaId = data["id"]
    query = '{ metadataById (id: ' + f"\"{metaId}\"" '){id created config}}'
    result = schema_id.execute(query)
    return flask.make_response(result, 200)
```

Here the end user can just make the JSON request and doesn't need to know about the graphql query.